# How to prevent the Network Location dialog (home, work, public) appearing for new connections?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, windows-vista, location

I've written a piece of software that uses an USB 3G Dongle to connect to the internet if a connection doesn't already exist.

When the software loads, it detects whether the internet is available and if not, then creates a dial up connection (via RAS) and then dials it.

If this happens for the first time, the network location dialog comes up asking the user to select whether it's home, work or public.

Is there anyway, I can either programatically set the network location of a connection, or even tell windows not to show the dialog and automatically set the location to public?

Cheers

Gavin

Edit: For ScottM

```
public bool Connect(bool monitorSignalUpdates)
{
    RasPhoneBook rpb = new RasPhoneBook();
    rpb.Open(true);
    if (!rpb.Entries.Contains("3G Connection"))
    {
        rpb.Entries.Add(RasEntry.CreateBroadbandEntry("3G Connection", RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G Modem", RasDeviceType.Modem), true));
    }
    _rd = new RasDialer();
    _rd.EntryName = "3G Connection";
    _rd.PhoneNumber = "*99#";
    try
    {
        _rd.Dial();
        if (monitorSignalUpdates)
        {
            _queryPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_queryPort_DataReceived);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        int i = 99;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1, my suspicion is not, but it's interesting none-the-less.

Comment: I couldn't tell you how, but my bet is that you could just simulate adding a network connect (do what the new network program does), and then in your program forgo the new network dialog.  Or just click the button when it comes up.

Comment: Can you post some code on how you are creating the connection? I've done this by just creating a phone book entry and having RAS dial that directly without showing the dialog

Comment: hi all, I didn't get any notifications of your comments, so apologies for the delay in replying.

I'm using DotRas to create the DUN and then dialing it. See my original post for code.

Comment: @Mazzzzz: I don't think you can unfortunately. When ever creating a new dial up connection or network within Windows now, the network location dialog will appear. That said, I do think there is a way to suppress it by telling it to set all new connections to Public.

Comment: @Gavin Have you tried setting RasEntry.Options.ShowDialingProgress to false?

Answer (score 2):

This registry entry controls whether Windows will prompt for ("Home/Work/Public"):

HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\NewNetworkWindowOff

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252535%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

You can always "“Turn off Notification on New Networks” from system tray :)

And if you can do that, I'm sure there's a registry hack and/or a PowerShell API for doing the same:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725831%28v=ws.10%29.aspx