# Keep Network Location Wizard from popping up after using RasDial to establish a VPN connection?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-7, vpn

I'm establishing a connection to my VPN using

- `RasSetEntryProperties` to create a new phone-book entry,
- `RasSetCredentials` to add credentials to that phone-book entry,
- `RasGetEntryDialParams` to get the parameters for RasDial,
- and `RasDial` to eventually establish a new connection.

After a little hassle it all works like a charm now. The only downside is that pesky Network Location Wizard popping up (on Windows Seven at least) every single time I connect to my VPN like I described above. How can I prevent that from happening programmatically?

Comment: It can be disabled with user level scope; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252535(v=ws.10).aspx have you tried creating a phonebook entry only once (i.e if its not present) then updating it? That UI should only appear for new connections

Comment: It pops up whenever I establish a _new_ connection, because I remove the entry after hanging up every time. And thank you, the link helped me a lot! It's a little hackish and slacky IMHO to modify the registry and change it back after, but it works pretty well. I was hoping for a WinAPI function tho, hehe.

Comment: I'm not sure since this hasn't been solved too (so I don't know if that helps), apparently ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488765/how-to-prevent-the-network-location-dialog-home-work-public-appearing-for-ne ), but have you tried to set `RasEntry.Options.ShowDialingProgress` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-optimal solution. The window will still pop up for a split second, but it will close almost immediately. Use the following [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com) script:

```
WinWaitActive("Network Location Wizard")
WinClose ("Network Location Wizard")
```

AutoIt scripts can be easily compiled into executables, you could then add the following line after your C/C++ code:

```
system("start Your_Autoit_script.exe");
```

This would launch the script immediately after your code, the script would then wait for the Network Location Wizard to pop up (WinWaitActive), and then it would close it.

There are two side effects for using this method:

1. The window will still show up for a very short period of time.
2. A tray icon will appear for a very short period of time.

Your users do not need to install AutoIt, the generated executable is independent.

EDIT: also see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6589283/2347534).

Answer (score 0):

If you call these functions from Session 0 (i.e. a windows service running as the system user) then you won't get the popup.  This is because of session 0 isolation.

If you have sufficient privileges to run your code as a service then this will solve your issue, if not I don't think there is anything in the API to help you unfortunately.